# Prevent getting a duppicate data from the database in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm trying to get data from the database filtered by some categories

This is my code in CodeIgniter

```
$this->db
    ->select('*')
    ->from($this->table)
    ->join('sites','sites.id = categories_by_site.site_id')
    ->where('categories_by_site.category_id', $categories[0])
    ->or_where('categories_by_site.category_id', $categories[1])
    ->order_by('id', 'ASC')
    ->get()
    ->result();
```

I simplify my code for the sake of this question, the above query take the categories as a search filter and used it to get result from the database.

There can be many categories filter to search at the same time, that's why I am using `or_where()` method.

The problem with this, when I got the result data, it has duplicate row of entries in object array.

Anyone can suggest how to prevent from getting a duppicate data from the database using above query?

Thanks

Comment: use *distinct* or *group by*

Comment: the table `categories_by_site` has the `category_id` or `site_id` field as PK(primary key) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `group_by` to solve this issue

Replace your code with

```
$this->db
    ->select('*')
    ->from($this->table)
    ->join('sites','sites.id = categories_by_site.site_id')
    ->where('categories_by_site.category_id', $categories[0])
    ->or_where('categories_by_site.category_id', $categories[1])
    ->order_by('id', 'ASC')
    ->group_by('categories_by_site.category_id')
    ->get()
    ->result();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can eleminate duplicate values using `distinct` or `group by`

As you select all fields a `group by` is better in my opinion. Example to group by `category_id`

`$this->db->group_by('category_id');`